# error : cache_dir must be a directory?

Tags: magento-1.7, cache, error

I am working with Magento 1.7 and suddenly I have this error when I go to cache management:

> cache_dir must be a directory

I tried this solution to change this file `lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php`

`'cache_dir' => 'null'` to `'cache_dir' => 'tmp/'` but does not work

Comment: what is you config in local.xml? do you have any specific settings for cache?

Comment: i don't use setting cache in local.xml

Comment: Create /var/tmp folder and give 777 file permission. This will solve your issue.

Answer (score 5):

Go to location `lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/` and open `file.php` and change: `null` to `NULL`

See:

```
protected $_options = array(
    'cache_dir' => NULL,
    'file_locking' => true,
```

Comment: I thougt the cache_dir error was about /var/cache, but it seems about something else. Can you explain whats going on because this fixed my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that your var and var/cache directories are writable.
The issue generally arises when var directory is not writable.

Comment: var and var/cache directories are writable (all privileges 777)

Comment: Also Check permissions for media directory, if works then good or Try this - Go to location lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/ and open file.php and change 'cache_dir' => 'null', to 'cache_dir' => 'full path to magento root directory/tmp'

Comment: I have the same problem :(

Comment: I tried all solutions searched but i have the same problem

Answer (score 2):

from Magento CE1.4 the 'cache_dir' value should be NULL without the quotes.

Also make sure the var/cache directory exists and is writeable and try and create a writeable `tmp` dir in your root.

I think [this post](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/17358/) might be related to your issue

Comment: but i have this error when cache_dir=>null

Comment: In your question the value is `'null'`, I've had this before with a upgrade where I had to change it to `null`. Also make sure that this file isn't overwritten in the local code dir :)

Comment: I re-edit my cache_dir=>'null' as default and i don't understand what file in the local dir ?

Comment: Zend libraries can be overwritten from app/code/local/Zend/...

Comment: i don't have Zend libreries in app/code/local

Comment: I've edited my answer with some other options

Comment: I tried that solutions but does not work i have the same error

Comment: I tried all solutions searched but i have the same problem

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found a little strange solution. I just add a new directory magento/null (777) in magento and it's resolved my problem.

It's strange

Comment: In that case it was expecting the path to a directory as a string. I bet if you change it to 'var/cache' it'll work with the old caching directory.

Comment: yes it's true it's work with 'var/cache'. Why other solutions does not work with me? can you explain me?

Comment: and you're sure it doesn't work if you change the value to `null` without quotes around it?

Comment: without cache_dir=>null doesn't work and with cache_dir=>'null' it's work when i add null directory in magento root

Comment: Hm very strange, well good it works now

Comment: Thanks Sander Manger for your help in this question and my others questions :)

Answer (score 2):

In my case multiple instances of Magento are running in different directories so absolute paths were required instead of relative paths in `lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php`.

Relative: `'cache_dir' => 'var/tmp/'`

Absolute: `'cache_dir' => '/var/www/domain.com/var/tmp/'`

This is a sample server environment, yours will be different so don't copy that line.

`var/tmp` already existed and permissions didn't matter.  The issue in my case is a configuration apparently from the installation.  When running a `diff` from command line on the `/downloader/` directory there are inconsistencies in the `*.cfg` files in the instances where the Magento Connect (/downloader/) would not display.

Answer (score 2):

Open `/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php`. Line 99  `'cache_dir' => 'var/tmp/'`

So Magento is trying to refer `/var/tmp/` folder and either it couldn't be able to read or write this folder.

So you got 2 solutions,

**Solution 1:** Give `777` file permission to `/var/tmp/` folder.

**Solution 2:** Open `/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php`. Change line 99 to  `'cache_dir' => 'null'`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I just created a `/tmp` directory in my Magento 1.7 root, and gave it 777 permissions. Magento didn't have permission to create the `/tmp` directory itself.