# Error log: cache_dir "‘tmp’" must be a directory

Tags: magento-1.9, error, ce-1.9.0.1, cache, file-permissions

I'm getting the error:

> cache_dir "‘tmp’" must be a directory

Trace:

```
#0 lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php(178): Zend_Cache::throwException('cache_dir "???t...')
#1 lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php(129): Zend_Cache_Backend_File->setCacheDir('???tmp???')
#2 lib/Zend/Cache.php(153): Zend_Cache_Backend_File->__construct(Array)
#3 lib/Zend/Cache.php(94): Zend_Cache::_makeBackend('File', Array, false, false)
#4 lib/Zend/Locale/Data.php(314): Zend_Cache::factory('Core', 'File', Array, Array)
#5 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Html/Calendar.php(42): Zend_Locale_Data::getList('en_US', 'days')
#6 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Html_Calendar->_toHtml()
#7 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#8 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('calendar', true)
#9 app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page/head.phtml(33): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('calendar')
#10 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/krudmart/...')
#11 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#12 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#13 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#14 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#15 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('head', true)
#16 app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('head')
#17 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/krudmart/...')
#18 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#19 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#20 app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#21 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#22 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#23 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#24 app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php(180): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#25 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController->indexAction()
#26 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#27 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#28 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#29 app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#30 index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#31 {main}
```

> Error log record number: 428748724167

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your var and `var/cache directories` are writable.
The issue generally arises when `var directory` is not writable.

For one guy he commented this as solution:

**Finally I found a little strange solution. I just add a new directory magento/null (777) in magento and it's resolved my problem.**

Go to this [LINK](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7842/error-cache-dir-must-be-a-directory), there was a discussion for the same case.

Answer (score 0):

@RIZ KRUD ,`create a folder tmp under your magento` dir .It store magento zend cache here

Comment: I tried doing that and it is still not working.

Answer (score -1):

Create the "tmp" folder (e.g `/magento/public_html/tmp`)

Then run the command:

```
chmod 777 tmp
```